# How to extract azure subscriptions ID from local terminal

Tags: azure

I wanted to get azure subscriptions ID and other credentials once I log in using

> azure login

with my azure account. Are there any way to get my own credentials of azure like
AWS one by using the below commands

> cat ~/.aws/credentials

Comment: What is the type of credential do you expect? Access token?

Comment: yeah all of them

Comment: If you mean the access token of your account via the CLI command `az login`, then you can get it via command `cat ~/.azure/accessTokens.json`.

Comment: Any updates on the question? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you log in via the CLI command `az login` with your account, then you can get the access token through the command `cat ~/.azure/accessTokens.json`.